# Ground not rendering

Tags: rendering

For some reason, my ground is not showing up. It appears in the 3d view mode, but disappears when I render it. My ground is set to render, but it won't show up.[image: 3d view]
[image: Render]
[Here is the file](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49161)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Render Emitter" check box must be checked in the particle panel. If not, only the particles emitted are rendered.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now, and I can't thank you enough.